# partial specialised template as template argument

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20, c++-concepts, template-templates

let's say for example I have a function `foo()` taking a parameter pack `Ts`. The function however should only accept the parameter pack `Ts` if there is exactly one type meeting the requirements of `std::is_integral`. The following code I've written does exactly that as expected.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename> typename predicate, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

// this method only compiles if exactly one of the given template arguments is of an integral type
template <typename... Ts>
void foo() requires (count_if<std::is_integral, Ts...> == 1) {}

int main()
{
    foo<int, double, float>(); //this compiles
    //foo<int, long, float>(); //this doesn't, as it should
}
```

However, let's say the function `foo()` is being extended by a parameter of template type `T` like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename> typename predicate, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

// this method only compiles if one of the given template arguments is of an integral type
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T) requires (count_if<std::is_integral, Ts...> == 1) {}

int main()

{
    foo<double, int, double, float>(double{}); //this compiles
    foo<int, int, double, float>(int{}); //this compiles
    //foo<double, int, long, float>(double{}); //this doesn't, as it should
}
```

And now to my question: Is it possible, to make the predicate I'm giving to my `count_if` function dependent of the template parameter `T` of my function `foo()`?

For example, so I could check following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename> typename predicate, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T) requires (count_if<std::is_same<T, ?????> , Ts...> == 1) {}

int main()
{
    foo<double, int, double, float>(double{}); //this should compile, as there is exactly one type in parameter pack of type double
    foo<int, int, double, float>(int{}); //this should compile, as there is exactly one type in parameter pack of type int
    //foo<int, double, float>(); //this shouldn't compile, as there is no int in parameter pack
    //foo<double, double, double>(); //this shouldn't compile, as there are two doubles in paramter pack
}
```

Is this somehow possible? I tried to check it using `static_assert()` inside the function body, but I can not define a template struct inside it, which I would need so I could write my own predicate like this for example:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T) 
{
  template <typename U>
  struct custom_predicate
  {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T, U>::value;
  };
    
  static_assert(count_if<custom_predicate, Ts...> == 1);
}
```

But like I said this isn't possible because I can't define template structs inside a function body.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you're looking for

```
template <template <typename, typename> typename predicate, typename T, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<T, Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T) requires (count_if<std::is_same, T, Ts...> == 1) {}
```

But, this way, you have to change the `count_if` requirements.

If you want (as you tried in the `static_assert()` example) a way to generate a specific `is_same` fixing the first type, you can write something similar your `custom_predicate` but outside the functions.

For example

```
template <template <typename> typename predicate, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

template <typename T>
struct my_predicate
 {
   template <typename U>
   using my_is_same = std::is_same<T, U>;
 };

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T) requires (count_if<my_predicate<T>::template my_is_same, Ts...> == 1)
 { /* ... */ }
```

Or maybe, to be more flexible (and passing the same `std::is_same` as parameter)

```
template <template <typename> typename predicate, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t count_if = ((predicate<Ts>::value ? 1 : 0) + ...);

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct my_predicate
 {
   template <typename ... Us>
   using my_is_same = C<Ts..., Us...>;
 };

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void foo(T)
   requires (count_if<my_predicate<std::is_same, T>::template my_is_same, Ts...> == 1)
 { }
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, thank you. However, is this possible in a more general way? Something like `template <template <typename...> typename predicate, typename... Ts>` So it can support a variable sized template list for the predicate? You'd have to split the parameter pack `Ts...` depending on how many arguments the predicate take... I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: @user3520616 - You can write, in a more general way, `template <template<typename...> typename predicate` for the predicate. But then you have to write the counter to feed it; maybe someone else... but I don't see a way to feed `predicate` in a general way.

Comment: @user3520616 - Answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you the other code you shared really helps me!

Comment: @user3520616 - Answer improved again (adding flexibility).

Comment: @user3520616 - Exactly! Corrected. Thanks.